# Can a Z80 be powered at 3.3v and still run reliably at 3-4MHz?

Tags: power, z80

I have various Z80 CPU's in my parts bin.  Some are from Zilog and some are from other companies (IIRC).  Some of them are hard to see the part numbers so I can't tell who made them but I'm sure they are Z80's.

Anyway, I need to build a circuit that uses the Z80 as the primary CPU (mini-computer) but I want to connect it to 3.3v devices like the propeller or other microcontrollers.

I've looked in various datasheets that I can find but none of them mention if the CPU can be powered from 3.3v.  I read they can "tolerate" -0.3v to 7v on all input pins but nothing (that I can find) says they can be driven by a 3.3v power supply.

The frequency I would like to run the CPU would be the NTSC colorbust frequency of 3.57954 MHz but it could go as high as 4 MHz.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: The definitive answer is in the respective datasheet, however  NMOS parts probably won't work at all at 3.3V, newer CMOS ones may work, at some speed.

Comment: This is a dumb question since it is directly and clearly answered in the datasheet right where you'd expect to find it.

Comment: I looked in the datasheet.  If I expected to find it there (which I did), but DIDN'T find it there, then I obviously overlooked it.  Hence, the nature of this question.  In fact, it's all in the datasheets.  Every answer.  So why have this site at all.

Comment: This project is a reverse engineered z80 that runs on modern FPGAs http://opencores.org/project,a-z80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datasheet says Vcc= 5 V ±5%.
At the time the Z80 was introduced 3.3V logic was completely uncommon (if not non-existent).

Cf. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_family#Monolithic_integrated_circuit_logic_families_compared) table about different logic families, typical supply voltages and year of introduction.

The Z80 dates back to the time when TTL-LS (low-power-Schottky) was common.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I must have missed that in the datasheet.  Do you know if there is a 3.3v version of the Z80?  Thanks

Comment: I know that later there were/are CMOS versions (e.g. from Hitachi). Maybe some of them can run on lower voltages, I'm not sure though. YOu have to find the datasheets

Comment: There are also more modern controllers containing a Z80 core (i.e. CPU + some peripherals and memory on-chip; not just a plain Z80 CPU). They probably run at 3.3V.

Comment: Do you have an example of one?

Comment: e.g. Zilog "Z8 Encore!"

Comment: AH, I think that might be a better solution.  If you want to post this as an answer I will accept.  I will do the research but hopefully it will be 100% compatible with Z80 code.  Which I can't imagine it wouldn't be.  THanks

Comment: I just found that the Z8 is similar but NOT compatible to the Z80...

Comment: Ah, then yeah that might be an issue.  I've been looking on Zilog's site and there are many different versions so it's hard to tell if any of them would work.  But, if the core Z8 isn't compatible with the Z80 then more than likely none of them will work.  So I may just have to live with using level shifters.